# Need to create function to optimise and make more efficient

Tags: c++

I've written this code that writes coordinates to a text file. I then use excel to plot these coordinates and it creates a rectangle with circles in it.
It works completing fine, but I want to optimize it. I thought I could optimize it by creating another function that has the syntax for the coordinates so I can call the function rather than writing it out every time and repeating the code. However, I am not sure how to do this, I have tried but its not working so some help would be really appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
#define PI 3.14159265

//this is the function i am trying to create
double coordinate_syntax(double x_coordinate, double y_coordinate){
    return map << x_coordinate << ' ' << y_coordinate << endl;
}

int build_environment_map(){

    double x0[5]={0.8, 0.8, 1.7, 2.2, 2.25};
    double y0[5]={1.5, 2.25, 1.0, 1.3, 0.25};
    double r=0.125, wallLength=2.5;
    double RD=PI /180;
    ofstream map;
    map.open("EnvironmentMap.txt");

    // The following code is to create a charger based on its centre.
    for (int i=0; i<360; i=i+20) {
        map << x0[4] + r*cos(i*RD) << ' ' << y0[4] + r*sin(i*RD) << endl;
        //coordinate_syntax( x0[4] + r*cos(i*RD), y0[4] + r*sin(i*RD) );
    }
    for (int i=0; i<360; i=i+10) {
        map << x0[0] + r*cos(i*RD) << ' ' << y0[0] + r*sin(i*RD) << endl;
        //coordinate_syntax(x0[0]+ r*cos(i*RD), y0[0]+ r*sin(i*RD));
    }
    for (double j=0 ; j<wallLength; j=j+0.01){
        map << j << ' ' << 0 << endl;
        //coordinate_syntax(j,0);
    }
    for (double x=0.3; x<0.55; x=x+0.01){
        map << x << ' ' << 0.3 << endl;
        //coordinate_syntax(x, 0.3);
    }
    map.close();
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int i;
    //calling the function
    i = build_environment_map();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Replace `endl` with '\n'

Comment: Hi bilbo! Questions about working code/optimizations are often off topic on this site. There is a separate forum for this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, there you might find other insights and tips

Comment: Some kind of binary format would be more efficient than text.

Comment: hello, is this a better way of writing it? if so, would you be able to explain why?

Comment: Your function doesn't work because you don't pass `map` to it and it doesn't return a `double`. You could change to `void coordinate_syntax(ostream& map, double x_coordinate, double y_coordinate) { map << x_coordinate << ' ' << y_coordinate << '\n'; }`
}

Comment: @bilbo_slagins If there is no obvious problem with your code and you just want a review or general tips, the question might be more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Questions here require a clear problem statement.